# Convert Python datetime to firestore timestamp format

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I've been uploading the results of my code to a firestore database, and I need to check when certain conditions were met during the execution of the program.
Currently, I've been saving these times as strings derived from datetime.now() objects, so I have something like:

```
start_t = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f")
stop_t = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f")
```

After some elaboration, these events are checked and some of them should be uploaded to a document in a firestore database, which now I'm doing by:

```
db_ref.collection(u'events').document(doc_ID).set({
                u'start_time': start_t,
                u'stop_time': stop_t)
            }, merge=True)
```

Instead of uploading the strings derived from datetime as I'm currently doing, I would need to create fields in the document with the corresponding timestamp...is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: Generally, people do not store timestamps as formatted strings in Firestore.  They use Firestore's native timestamp field type, which you can populate with a native date object or the Firestore SDK's built-in timestamp type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad, I didn't know I could directly upload a datetime object to firestore, and it creates a timestamp.

So, I just converted the strings back to datetime (using datetime.strptime) and uploaded them by:

```
db_today_ref.collection(u'events').document(doc_ID).set({
    u'start_time': datetime.strptime(start_t, '%Y_%m_%d%H_%M_%S_%f'),
    u'stop_time': datetime.strptime(stop_t, '%Y_%m_%d%H_%M_%S_%f')
    }, merge=True)
```